# C++ constexpr overloads constructor with same name

Tags: c++, class, overloading, constexpr

I do understand the use of `constexpr` when using it on expressions that can be calculated before runtime.

I want to create a constexpr for complex numbers. `x = 5_i` should create an complex number of my own complex class I have created and to do it I need a `constantexpr constructor`.

```
class Complex {
private:
    double real_;
    double imag_;

public:
    ...
    Complex(double real, double imaginary);

    constexpr Complex(double real, double imaginary):
        real_(real),imag_(imaginary) {};

//Nonmember function
constexpr Complex operator""_i(long double arg);
```

The `Complex(double real, double imaginary);`is later defined in the .cpp file.
When I try to compile this, I get the following error :

```
‘constexpr Complex::Complex(double, double)’ cannot be overloaded with  
‘Complex::Complex(double, double)’
```

If I define just the `constexpr` function my conclusion is that I cannot use `Complex::Complex(double, double)` in runtime.

Why cannot I define two different functions? Is this not allowed in C++? Can the compiler not see the difference between the two functions? Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Are you familiar with `#include <complex>` and `std::complex<T>` ?  BTW, I remember something about the contents of a complex type having to be of the form `T value[2]`, but why I cannot recall.

Comment: @JiveDadson will probably not use my own complex class, but the goal here is to get to know C++. I could not understand everything about `constexpr` by reading online. The [2] is probably because it's an real and imaginary part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if you define it [`constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_initialization) you can still use it at run-time. You do not need two different overloads and you cannot overload only on `constexpr`.

The `constexpr` [User-defined literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) need [`constexpr` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) so that the compiler can create and initialize objects of the class at compile-time. The `constexpr` constructor places some restrictions on the constructor but allows [constant initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_initialization).

```
constexpr Complex a = 1.0_i;
const Complex b = 1.0_i;
```

If you look at the [`std::complex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/complex) you'll see that it also have `constexpr` constructors.

Comment: Can a program still use `constexpr` to allocate new Complex numbers in runtime? Like allocating new space with `new` for a complex number in a for loop and using `Complex(r,i)`?

Answer (score 1):

I would not roll my own complex type. Leave the drudgery to the library writers, hunched over their keyboards like medieval monks copying manuscripts.

I do not know why the operator has to take `long double` rather than just `double`, but that's the law.

```
#include <complex>
using Complex = std::complex<double>;

constexpr Complex operator"" _i (long double val) {
    return Complex(0.0,  static_cast<double>(val));
}
```

Comment: I will probably not use my own `complex class`, but the goal here is to get to know C++. I could not understand everything about `constexpr` by reading online. I'll give you plus one for talking about that the `operator""` only can take certain types. It can only receive `long double` and not `double`.  I read it somewhere on `Stack Overflow` a few minutes ago but I cannot find it.

Comment: The answer is in the C++ standard for my comment. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal